# PDO SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo, bind, statements

Im stuck on this one, recently switched to PDO to learn myself.

```
/**
* update
* @param string $table A name of a table to update into
* @param string $data An associative array.
* @param string $where WHERE = ?.
*/
public function update($table, $dataArr, $where)
{
    $fieldDetails = NULL;

    foreach( $dataArr as $key => $value)
    {
        $fieldDetails .= "`$key` =:$value, ";
    }
    $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails,', ');

    echo "UPDATE $table SET ($fieldDetails) WHERE (`id`=:$where)";


    $stmt = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET ($fieldDetails) WHERE (`id`=:$where)");
    foreach($dataArr as $key => $value) 
    {
        //Binder key till värde.
        $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }
    $stmt->bindValue(":$where", $where);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

My insert function works like a charm, but this update function won't work. I think it has to do with the id no being bind. I have searched in documentation and threads but can't find an solution.

My function call.

```
public function update()
{
    $this->db->update(
    'testtable',
    array(
    'text' => 'exempel',
    'name' => 'exempel',
    ), 0);
}
```

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

How do I correctly bind the integer value I pass in with the function, to so that the statement can be executed ?.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Well, I overlooked the code, my apologies.
Anyway, your code is open to SQL injection, and it would be better to use a solution from the [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

By the way, when using not a stone-age libraries like PDO, but [something more useful](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), you won't need no update() function at all, as you can write simply

```
$db->query("UPDATE ?n SET ?u WHERE id=?i",$table, $dataArr, $id);
```

please note that this latter code **is much safer** than yours, yet way more flexible:

- it does protect table name
- it does protect field names
- it lets you not only id-based WHERE but whatever condition.
- it lets you whatever syntax (even JOINs) actually

Comment: What libs do you recommend that not has a too high learning curve ?

Comment: One I linked to - SafeMysql. In my opinion, it has no learning curve at all - you just write usual SQL, substituting dynamical parts with placeholders and get results in one function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldDetails .= "`$key` =:$key, ";
```

You need to put the key name as placeholder here, not the value.

Comment: what about the last `,` ?

Comment: What about it? It's trimmed afterwards. Actually, an `implode` call would be better overall, but that's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: This code is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @You If the keys are arbitrary user supplied values, yes. If they're whitelisted, no.

Comment: There is no word `'if'` in terms of injection protection. Either your code vulnerable or not. I'd be happy to remove a downvote if you bother to format the field name properly

Comment: No because I want the $value to be the data that goes in to the database.

Comment: @egilviking But you need the placeholder to be the name of the key, because you're later binding the value using the name of the key!

Comment: @egilviking in this part deceze is right. you need your SET to look like `name=:name, age=:age` and so on. Keys, not values.

Comment: @You Fair enough. I typically never write code like this with dynamic field names, my field names are always present in the query I write. I'd suggest that over such overly dynamic queries to begin with.